# "Syndicate something to boot" Definition

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the bolded part?

> Fewer people seek critical opinion, especially when they’ve been bludgeoned by aggressive (and effective, as it turns out) viral marketing campaigns that extend far beyond traditional means, and editors are conscious of this fact. Why pay salary and benefits for a single critic when you can hire three free-lancers for less money, and **syndicate their 250-word minireviews to boot?**

does it mean ignore their 250-word mini reviews?

Comment: "*To boot*" means "*as well*", "*in addition*", or "*on top of that*". "*Syndicate*" you can look in a dictionary (and no, it does not mean "*ignore*").

Comment: Yes; 'to boot' is a rather old-fashioned term. Here, the usage is not all that clear, so I'll add a clearer example: _Blackbeard was a pirate, and a mean-hearted, evil one to boot._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not so old fashioned. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+boot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20boot%3B%2Cc0) shows it has been gaining popularity for the past 2 decdes, and is now as common as it was 100 years ago. It's only been higher in the 1820's and 1830's.

Comment: [to boot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/boot?q=to+boot#boot-2)

Comment: @Barmar Yes: I'm being too parochial. 'To boot' is not used as commonly in British English as was once the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Bron's comment beneath the poster's question observes, "to boot" simply means "as well," "at the same time," "on top of that," or "too."

Another thing that may be baffling the poster is the absence of the phrase "when you can" just before the bolded wording in the quoted sentence. Though that phrase goes unstated, it is certainly implicit in the original wording. Still, we could restate the final sentence in the block quote as follows, for maximum clarity:

> Why pay salary and benefits for a single critic when you can hire three freelancers for less money, and when you can syndicate their 250-word minireviews, too?

Comment: There's also a general connotation that the addition is a bonus or improvement of some kind, like the metaphor "icing on the cake".